# Put a Default value in a inputbox which must dissapear on click

Tags: default, inputbox

I have a inputbox, I want to write a default value in it, and when I click in the inputbox that default value dissapear...

Can somebody please help me with this? What is the easiest way in achieving this?

Thanks. Cheers. Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer:
[How can I implement Stack Overflow-like watermarks in forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260367/how-can-i-implement-stack-overflow-like-watermarks-in-forms)

In short, HTML5 has the placeholder attribute, which is designed for this very task.

Comment: I tried this code now. It works great but the issue is the AFTER you click on the inputbox and then click somewhere else on the site (OUT the inputbox) the default text that was don't come up again in the inputbox (but is seen in the Source Code...) Is there a fix for this? Thank you

Comment: What browser/version are you using? `Placeholder` works only in webkit and maybe FF at the moment. You're likely safest going with the accepted answer listed at the question I linked to. (It provides you with some simple javascript events you can attach to your `<input` box...

Comment: Using Google Chrome, last version

Comment: Using Google Chrome, last version, yes I tried that code from the link you wrote... but if it works only in some browsers I guess I will not use it.. thanks anyway

Comment: No, that javascript code will work in ALL browsers....the placeholder will work only on select browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060265/html5-placeholder-support

Answer (score 1):

That's called a watermark. Check this jQuery plugin out http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/.